# How to Efficiently Parallelize AES-CTR PRNG Implementation in C Using Pthreads for Multi-Core Utilization?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, aes

I am working on improving the `nwipe` tool, specifically by implementing an AES-CTR PRNG using AES-128 in counter mode to generate high-quality random numbers for securely wiping HDDs and SSDs. The original implementation runs on a single core, and I am trying to parallelize it using pthreads to utilize all available CPU cores. However, my attempt at parallelization has resulted in a significant performance drop, and I'm seeking advice on how to correct this.

Here's the single-core implementation that works correctly but only utilizes one core:

```c
int nwipe_aes_ctr_prng_read(NWIPE_PRNG_READ_SIGNATURE) {
    u8* restrict bufpos = buffer;
    size_t words = count / SIZE_OF_AES_CTR_PRNG;

    for(size_t ii = 0; ii < words; ++ii) {
        aes_ctr_prng_genrand_uint128_to_buf((aes_ctr_state_t*) *state, bufpos);
        bufpos += 16; // Move to the next block
    }

    // Handle remaining bytes if count is not a multiple of SIZE_OF_AES_CTR_PRNG
    const size_t remain = count % SIZE_OF_AES_CTR_PRNG;
    if(remain > 0) {
        unsigned char temp_output[16]; // Temporary buffer for the last block
        aes_ctr_prng_genrand_uint128_to_buf((aes_ctr_state_t*) *state, temp_output);
        memcpy(bufpos, temp_output, remain);
    }

    return 0; // Success
}
```

My attempt to implement pthreads for parallelization is as follows, but it has led to a performance decrease from 200MB/s to around 15MB/s:

```c
typedef struct {
    aes_ctr_state_t* state;
    u8* buffer;
    size_t start;
    size_t end;
} prng_thread_arg_t;

void* nwipe_aes_ctr_prng_read_thread(void* arg) {
    prng_thread_arg_t* thread_arg = (prng_thread_arg_t*)arg;
    aes_ctr_state_t* state = thread_arg->state;
    u8* buffer = thread_arg->buffer + thread_arg->start;
    size_t words = (thread_arg->end - thread_arg->start) / SIZE_OF_AES_CTR_PRNG;

    for(size_t ii = 0; ii < words; ++ii) {
        aes_ctr_prng_genrand_uint128_to_buf(state, buffer);
        buffer += SIZE_OF_AES_CTR_PRNG;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int nwipe_aes_ctr_prng_read(NWIPE_PRNG_READ_SIGNATURE) {
    int num_threads = 8; // Adjustable based on requirements
    pthread_t threads[num_threads];
    prng_thread_arg_t thread_args[num_threads];

    size_t total_words = count / SIZE_OF_AES_CTR_PRNG;
    size_t words_per_thread = total_words / num_threads;

    for(int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        size_t start = i * words_per_thread * SIZE_OF_AES_CTR_PRNG;
        size_t end = (i + 1) * words_per_thread * SIZE_OF_AES_CTR_PRNG;

        if(i == num_threads - 1) {
            end = total_words * SIZE_OF_AES_CTR_PRNG; // Correct end calculation
        }

        thread_args[i].state = (aes_ctr_state_t*)*state;
        thread_args[i].buffer = buffer;
        thread_args[i].start = start;
        thread_args[i].end = end;

        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, nwipe_aes_ctr_prng_read_thread, &thread_args[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    // Remaining bytes handling omitted for brevity
    return 0;
}
```

Both attempts, use the following function in order to generate the numbers.

```
void aes_ctr_prng_genrand_uint128_to_buf(aes_ctr_state_t* state, unsigned char* bufpos) {
    CRYPTO_ctr128_encrypt(bufpos, bufpos, 16, &state->aes_key, state->ivec, state->ecount, &state->num, (block128_f) AES_encrypt);
    next_state(state);
}
```

**Question**: What could be the cause of the performance drop when parallelizing with pthreads, and how can I efficiently use all cores for the AES-CTR PRNG implementation?

I appreciate any insights or suggestions you may have. Thank you!

Comment: Start with a thread count of 1. See if you get similar performance to your non-threaded/original code. Gradually increase the number of threads (you'll probably get a bell curve for performance). If you're CPU bound, more threads may help. But, if you're memory bus bound (e.g. fetching/storing lots of memory), you may get cache misses (because your threads bounce the controller and you get less locality-of-reference) and, more importantly, you could max out the memory bus. This can happen with as little as 4 threads.

Comment: I have to assume that `state` is an argument in `NWIPE_PRNG_READ_SIGNATURE`? And, are you sure that you can use the _same_ `state` value in _all_ threads? That _looks_ suspicious. And, the _cast_ in `thread_args[i].state = (aes_ctr_state_t*)*state;` looks suspicious. What is the definition of `state` (without the macro argument trickery)?

Comment: Note that OpenMP can be significantly simpler to create threads like this. It is supported by all mainstream compilers (though it may require some tricks for MSVC) in C and C++ including GCC and Clang. Parallelizing a code with it is as simple as adding the line `#pragma omp parallel for` before a for loop. Variables are shared by default and can be made private with `private(your_variable_name)`, or `firstprivate(your_variable_name)` for a copy of an existing variable. For just creating threads, it is `#pragma omp parallel`.

Comment: Anything that is fast enough for that tool is being an SSD or RAM.  SSD's won't be overwriting the original data. So you might as well write zero's to have the same kind of protection on a system / sector level (to avoid logical undelete's). Similar for RAM really, getting old information from RAM is pretty tricky and I don't think it is would be common scenario. That all said, I've created something similar where buffers were filled and put into a queue to be released and then reused, possibly by a different thread. Maybe that's a good way of attacking this?

Comment: I mean something [like this (link to ChatGPT)](https://chat.openai.com/share/83f2d509-ccdb-41b0-8380-423e13fc9860). Alternatively you could have a buffer per thread, check if it is filled and after using indicate that the thread should regenerate. I'm a bit afraid that sharing memory while having threads on multiple cores will mess up the speed.

Comment: Your application is to wiping storage devices.  My first guess would be that this is I/O bound, not CPU bound.  if so, then parallelization is futile: it cannot improve performance, but it *can* harm performance.